# How to handle the autorotation in each view controller in ios 8?

Tags: ios, ios8, autorotate

The scenario is like this:

lets say ViewControllers A, B.

A supports only portrait mode. B supports all modes.

I tap on thumbnail image from A and showing full image in B. So auto-rotation works fine in B. It works fine, If I come back to A from B when B is in portrait mode.

But the problem is if I keep my phone in landscape mode when I was in B then if I come back to A then it is also showing landscape which is not supposed to happen.

I was working totally fine in iOS7 but it is messing up in iOS 8.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at size classes once..!

Comment: @Avis444 Yeah I looked at them. But I don't understand exactly how to implement them. Can you provide me an example to implement them?

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your code. I just implemented it to test and it works fine.

I addded to A:

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Added to B:

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

and added the button to A to open B:

```
- (IBAction) buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"itShouldWork" bundle:nil];
    MyViewController *controller = (MyViewController *)[story instantiateInitialViewController];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

As I said, it works fine. tested on iphone 5 device (iOS 8). Built with Xcode 6

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in iOS 8.

As a workaround you can wrap your B controller in UINavigationController. Along with checking for iOS version it would look like

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8")) {
    [self presentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controllerB] animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [self presentViewController:controllerB animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Macros for checking iOS version can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/alex-cellcity/998472).